# Separation between texture bake and its margin

Tags: texture-baking

When I create a cycles bake it ends up with a line separating the texture and the extra margin.
I'm using the SimpleBake plugin, so I asked the creator about it, but it seems the problem also happens when using Blender's native option.

I'm in version 3.3.1 and have seen it happen in older versions.

My current solution is to blur the texture and resharpen, but I lose a lot of the detail.

It doesn't have any modifiers.

Blend file: https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArX_3p1KuCowl_9YT4j8-O-Md-IXlg?e=UGAS3h

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried every bake type but it looks like only the *Combined* bake type has this problem. Is there a reason why you want to use *Combined* and not bake 2 image textures  (base color & metal mask)? I wonder because you have a partly metallic material.

Comment: Blender 3.0 supports now denoising while baking. But **there is a bug T94573** [Regression: black seams in my Cycles bakes (caused by denoising) due to margin pixel extension darkening](https://developer.blender.org/T94573) which causes these artifacts. Since it's a bug, the only things you can do is turn off the *Cycles > Sampling > Render > Denoise* option, use other bake types or wait for a bug fix.

Comment: One more thing: the UV islands in the provided blend file have no margins at all. You should add a margin to them, otherwise baking a texture with a margin makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you!, like you said it is a bug with the denoiser, I just need to choose "denoise (compositor)" instead of "denoise (cycles)" and the separation disapears.

fix: https://imgur.com/a/L01KsNs